# Как переименовать базу данных?

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток.

Как переименовать существующую БД с помощью sql запроса из php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Сделайте бэкап всей исходной БД.**
2. [`RENAME TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/rename-table.html) позволяет переименовывать таблицы из одной БД в другую, при условии, что обе БД находятся на общей файловой системе.

   Так что надо создать новую БД, переименовать таблицы из старой в новую:

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE db_new;

   RENAME TABLE 
     db_old.table1 TO db_new.table1,
     db_old.table2 TO db_new.table2,
     ...
     db_old.tableN TO db_new.tableN
   ;
   ```
3. Проверьте, перенеслись ли таблицы, осталось ли что-то нужное в старой БД.
4. Удалите старую БД:

   ```
   DROP TABLE db_old;
   ```

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо. Мучался не 1 час, адекватной информации нигде не было.
Вот код, вдруг кому ешё понадобиться.

mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE `NEW_DB`");
$res = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM OLD_DB");
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    mysql_query("RENAME TABLE `OLD_DB`.`{$result['Tables_in_OLD_DB']}`
                  TO `NEW_DB`.`{$result['Tables_in_OLD_DB']}`;");
}
mysql_query("DROP DATABASE `OLD_DB`");

Comment: @Ford, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Насколько я помню, команду для переименования базы данных убрали из mysql.  
Чтобы переименовать, можно воспользоваться phpmyadmin, по-моему, там была такая возможность.  
Если у вас база с типом MyISAM, то можно просто переименовать каталог базы данных.  
Но мне кажется, что проще скопировать старую базу в новую с нужным названием и затем удалить старую.

P.S. Ну и, конечно, ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО не забывайте сделать бекап перед всеми манипуляциями.

**UPD**    
забыл сказать, если вы будете копировать базу с новым нужным именем, то не забудьте проверить права на новую базу данных.

Comment: да, [пишут](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/rename-database.html), что `RENAME DATABASE` был добавлен в `5.1.7`, сочтён небезопасным, и удалён уже в версии `5.1.23`.